# currentTime sets the time to 2-3 seconds before the set time in videojs on tizen tv application

Tags: video.js, tizen, tizen-web-app

I am using videojs in my web based tizen tv application for playing hls streams. I have seek feature on the videos where I set the currentTime to the user seeked time. Setting the `currentTime(n)` brings the video to `n-2` or `n-3` timestamp.

While same implementation works fine on latest chrome browser, this issue is observed sometimes in tizen 4.0 and similar versions. This might be due to the old chromium [version](https://developer.samsung.com/smarttv/develop/specifications/web-engine-specifications.html) on samsung tv.

I have searched about it but couldn't find any solution to this issue. I would highly appreciate any help around this.

Comment: We have faced a similar problem with Shaka player on Samsung. We did not get a convincing response when we contacted Samsung team. We had to add extra checks around our features involving currenttime, to ensure this did not cause issues.